# Determining whether there is a descending pattern between two sampled numbers

Tags: math, classification

I have two numbers that are samples of two different quantities (it doesn't really matter what it is). They are both fluctuating with time. I have samples for these values from two different points in time. Call them a0, a1, b0, b1. I can use the differences (a1-a0, b1-b0) the difference and sum of the differences ( (a1-a0)-(b1-b0) ) ( (a1-a0) + (b1-b0) ) )

My questions is how do you determine when both of them are descending in an fashion that doesn't hard code any constants. Let me explain.

I want to detect when both of these quantities have decreased by a certain amount but that amount may change if I change the quantities I'm sampling so I can't hard code a constant.

I'm sorry if this is vague but that's really all the information I have. I was just wondering if this is even solvable.

Comment: can't you multiply? can you compare to 0? if(a1-a0<0)?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( a1 - a0 < 0)
  if( b1 - b0 < 0) {
    //... descending
  }
```

or:

```
if ( a1 - a0 + b1 - b0 < a1 - a0)  // b1 - b0  is negative
  if( a1 - a0 + b1 - b0 < b1 - b0) {  // a1 - a0 is negative
    //... descending
  }
```

To add a threshold is simple:

```
if ( a1 - a0 < -K)
  if( b1 - b0 < -K) {
    //... descending, more than K
  }
```

or:

```
if ( a1 - a0 + b1 - b0 < a1 - a0 - K)  // b1 - b0  is less than -K
  if( a1 - a0 + b1 - b0 < b1 - b0 - K) {  // a1 - a0 is less than -K
    //... descending more than K
  }
```

Comment: But K is of a constant magnitude. Say the ranges of a and b change. Then K would have to change too.

Comment: @ballaw How is K related to these factorsv then? How can you code this if you can't express it?

Comment: I guess that's the problem with my question. I feel like K should be a percentage of maximum magnitude of change in a or b but I don't know how to get that from just two samples.

Comment: you have to make it clear even in pseudocode if I am to help you